# Как сделать бегущее изображение средствами CSS через свойство animation (@keyframes)?

Tags: html, css

Сейчас есть бегущее изображение, которое двигается постоянно справа налево, задано изображение через:

`background: url('/images/plashka.jpg') 0 0 repeat #fff;`

Как сделать так, чтобы изображение задавалось через тэг `<img>`?

Comment: если это не спрайт изображение, используйте тег ```img```

Comment: Тег то я использовал. Но изображение начинает движение с правой стороны блока (в моём случае с правой стороны окна, т.к. изображение широкое и по высоте маленькое). Я не знаю, как сделать так, чтобы изображение уже было на экране по всей длине блока, но двигалось оно infinite, т.е. бесконечно и плавно

Answer (score 0):

Задать его через тег img...))

```
<img src="URL" alt="альтернативный текст">
```

HTML:

```
<div class="pic"><img src="/images/pic.png" alt="Картинка"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.pic {animation-duration: 5s;
 animation-name: slidein;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite; } 



@keyframes slidein {
  from { margin-left: 0%; width: 100%;}
  to { margin-left: 100%;
  width: 300%;}}
```

[Демо](https://codepen.io/iliyasold/pen/KKRwPYo)

Comment: Привет. Это я смог сделать. Не смог сделать так, чтобы первоначальное изображение уже было на экране. Получилось только так, чтобы оно выходило с правого края экрана. Не могу задать начальное положение плашки на экране

Comment: HTML:
`<div class="lenta">
<img src="/images/plashka-clients.jpg" width="1229" height="130" alt="Наши клиенты" />
</div>`

CSS:
`.lenta {position:relative;background:#fff;border-radius:6px;margin:15px 0;box-shadow:0 2px 3px 0 #ccc,inset 10px 0 10px 0 #eee,inset -10px 0 10px 0 #eee;overflow:hidden;}
.lenta img {width:100%;max-width:1229px;height:130px;text-align:right;animation:clients_anim 250s linear infinite;animation-delay:0s;animation-direction:normal;animation-fill-mode:none;}`

Comment: Сорри, не знаю, как отформатировать текст с переносом строк...

Comment: Не совсем то, я посмотрел исправление коммента. 1) У меня широкое изображение (лента), ширина 1229 px, высота 130 px. Мне нужно, чтобы при загрузке страницы это изображение уже было у левого края, т.е. чтобы изображение было видно на всю ширину экрана, а непомещающаяся часть была скрыта с правой стороны. Изображение должно идти справа налево. Изображение должно циклично повторяться сразу, как лента пройдёт и без промежутков, т.е. как бы однородно. Так получилось сделать только через background-image + background-position. Но хотелось бы сделать через img

Comment: 1. Ты можешь поставить любое изображение, в чём проблема? 
2. Изображение будет на странице при загрузке.
3. Непомещающаяся часть будет скрыта - экран имеет ограничение)

Comment: 4. Перед тобо масса настроек - меняй их и будет тебе счастье. from - это ноль, to - 100%, слева направо. Надо справа налево - сделай наоборот. Задержка, итерации - всё настраивается. Посмотри доки. keyframes - это раскадровка. Эффекты в animation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations. Настраивай, пробуй и получишь то, что нужно.

Comment: Поправил пример. Теперь после загрузки встаёт справа на 2 сек. - меняй на 5, 105 - сколько хош. Движется бесконечно справа налево. Оставил комментарии в коде.

Comment: Привет. Вечером посмотрю. Да нет, мне не задержка изображения справа нужна была, а чтобы изображение было выведено на всю страницу, а не начинало движение с правого бока блока. Я про начальное положение изображения. Т.е., допустим, блок имеет width:500px, а img в нём width:1300px, то нужно, чтобы когда откроется страница сайта, то img был уже на весь блок, а не выдвигался с правой стороны блока, постепенно его заполняя. И при этом нужно, чтобы изображение шло постоянно, т.е. infinite :)

Comment: )) ...ничего не понятно, но очень интересно. Если ширина картинки больше ширины блока, то она по умолчанию займёт всю его ширину. Может есть картинка того, что тебе нужно или описание задачи на... литературном языке?)

Comment: Попробую угадать: https://codepen.io/iliyasold/pen/mdLyZBR

Comment: Да, последнее это то, что нужно. Но у меня не вышло сделать подобное с длинным изображением. В общем, всё удалось наладить, кроме отступа в конце анимации. Нужно сделать так, чтобы лента была "бесконечная". Вот как выглядит начало: https://radikal.host/i/Bm7Su , а вот так выглядит конец: https://radikal.host/i/BmDNr . На конечном изображении написано, что нужно убрать :)

Comment: HTML: `<div class="lenta"><img src="/images/plashka-clients.jpg" /></div>`

Comment: @iliyasold, CSS: `.lenta {overflow:hidden;}` и `.lenta img {display:block;width:1229px;max-width:none;height:130px;text-align:right;animation:clients_anim 100s linear infinite;animation-delay:0s;animation-direction:normal;animation-fill-mode:none;}` и `@keyframes clients_anim {0% {transform:translate(0%, 0);} 100% {transform:translate(-100%, 0);}}`

Comment: Поиграй со значениями margin-left - увидишь разницу и как это работает. Ну, или посчитай: какое значение нужно поставить, чтобы лента как бы "не прерывалась". Сопоставь с размером твоего изображения.

Comment: Да я то поигрался, только второй и последующий круг дёргает изображение. Лента неоднородная. Каждый новый круг анимации запускает новую прокрутку, оставляя в конце ленты пустое место. А мне нужно, чтобы лента была однородная, без разрывов! И margin-left:-1229px здесь не поможет, т.к. это лишь доведёт ленту за край блока, но никак не сделает её однородной

Comment: https://codepen.io/iliyasold/pen/yLjeVjO

Comment: Да, визуально оно. Но технически неправильно, т.к. браузер толкает два изображения, что нагружает его лишний раз. Это заметно на мобильном устройстве в плане производительности и вытекающих из этого остальных моментов. Я так понял, что сделать не костыльно получится только через background-image? В принципе, видимо поэтому я и не смог сделать через img :)

Comment: Нормально ты так прогулялся: начал с "как сделать через img и keyframes?", а закончил философическим рассуждением о производительности мобильного браузера)

Comment: Да не, не)) Я ценю твою помощь. Но два изображения вместо одного - плохо. Браузер же рендерит это всё. У меня сейчас мобила Сонька старая и она нагревается даже при прокрутке одного изображения, если на него смотреть 10 секунд. А будет два - вообще трэшняк)) Ну т.е. я не про синтетический тест рассказываю, а про действительность

Comment: Раньше у меня бегало изображение через background-image, всё было окей. Но мне нужно сделать разметку именно через тег img и пока я не смог решить задачу НОРМАЛЬНО ;)

Comment: Точно формулировать задачу - всё ещё хорошая, рабочая практика)

Comment: @iliyasold, в делах был. Ну, извиняй, как смог, так сформулировал. Скоро вернусь к этому всему. Пока что бек-энд...